# "on hold" 4.5 years after asking the question?

Tags: discussion, moderation

4.5 years, multiple editors touching it and 1400+ views later:

[MediaWiki editor with paste for graphics?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42713/mediawiki-editor-with-paste-for-graphics)

Was closed as off-topic.   Isn't this a bit silly?

Answer (score 6):

No, it isn't silly. We used to accept requests for recommendations, but we found that to be too problematic, so a couple of years ago the community decided that such questions are off-topic.

Your question has been closed because it's off-topic. Generally speaking, we don't go looking for such questions (and there are still plenty left), but if one comes across such a question the proper course of action would be to vote to close. That's how community moderation at Stack Exchange is supposed to work.

Your question is closed, not deleted. "Closed" simply means that no more answers can be added to it. It can still be voted on (as can its answers) and the content in the answers is still available. It may have some lasting value, so it'll stick around, but what we *don't* want is for people new to the site to post a recommendation question and point to old questions such as this as proof that they're allowed to ask similar questions.